# read json data sent from android in php

Tags: php, android

So my android app is reading the users contact list, then creating a JSONObject of it and sending that object as POST to my PHP Server, then my PHP Server will read the posted data and will store it in database. So far my progress -

Android Part --

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray();    
private void getDetails(){
        try {
            Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
            String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
            Cursor names = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int indexName = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int indexNumber = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

            names.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String name   = names.getString(indexName);
                String number = names.getString(indexNumber);
                JSONObject cust= new JSONObject();
                cust.put("name",name);
                cust.put("mobile",number);

                obj.put(cust);
            } while (names.moveToNext());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

               try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contactList", obj.toString()));
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://doupnow.com/Demo/sendContact.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    Log.d("Server Response",entity.toString());
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {

                }
```

The `JSON` data created is --

```
[{"mobile":"+1-703-349-3003","name":"Consultant Veshakptnam"},
 {"mobile":"+91 33 3057 0062","name":"Niit Subhashis"},
 {"mobile":"+91 33 3057 0074","name":"Vivek Rawat NIIT HO"}]
```

This is my php page --

```
<?php 
    require_once('config.php');

    $data = json_decode($_POST["contactList"]);

    foreach ($data as $d1) 
    {
        $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("insert into demo set name=?,mobile=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $d1->name,$d1->mobile);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    mysqli_close($linkID1);

    echo 0;
?>
```

But my data is not getting stored in mysql, is there any problem in reading the json data. kindly guide me.Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure that you get the data from the server? Try to log first before saving to database.

Comment: Did you get any error? Please provide if you get any.

Comment: how to log the data

Comment: you need to debug your php code. Just search how to debug php

Comment: @JimmyGupta Check if you're receiving string in $_POST["contactList"].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your PHP code might be receiving JSON, but as an Object, It must be received as a JSON String to decode.

Refer [this](https://eval.in/939677) for your understanding. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: he did put objects inside array, check the `obj` variable type where he `obj.put()` the contact object.

Comment: To downvoter : Sometimes you need to try the solution by yourself. Just reviewing code won't work. Anyways the  answer is accepted ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not on how you read your json data, but how you insert it into the database. Instead of
    `$stmt = $linkID1->prepare("insert into demo set name=?,mobile=?");`
put
`$stmt = $linkID1->prepare("insert into demo(name,mobile) values(?,?)");`

Comment: @jimmy This is your problem (and solution)

Comment: @ariefbayu `"insert into demo set name=?,mobile=?"` and `"insert into demo(name,mobile) values(?,?)"` both works.